# Can you "win" a grant?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say that someone is awarded a monetary grant to study in an University X for 3 years.

Is it correct to say, for instance in a CV, "**Winner** of a grant for a period of study of 3 years at University X"? That "winner" word doesn't sound completely right to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you competed for the grant against other people, then winner is possibly correct. There is no reason to feel awkward in admitting that you won a grant over several other people. Quite the opposite, you are to be congratulated.

If the grant was given to you by a person or organisation that wanted to assist you personally, then you could say that you were the "Recipient of a grant...". If the grant was earned as a result of high grades obtained during a course of study, but without any direct competition, then you could say that you were "Awarded a grant..."